# what's the arbitrum address for EURT?

Tags: etherscan, arbitrum, tether

I would like to get the arbitrum address for EURt: `0xC581b735A1688071A1746c968e0798D642EDE491`

https://etherscan.io/token/0xC581b735A1688071A1746c968e0798D642EDE491

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like arbitrum supports EURt.

https://www.coingecko.com/en/categories/arbitrum-ecosystem

Comment: what about (google search): https://arbiscan.io/token/0xd5799afb5711f374095a3e640ff347056f7deadc?
scam coin?

Comment: It does seem that way, there are only 4 holders and the total supply is 250 EURT. 
I would wait for an official message from Tether or for it to be listed officially. Where have you heard that there is EURt on Arbitrum ?

Comment: I never heard of it. I'm getting interested in EURt and naturally thought of using it via Arbitrum (just like I already do with USDt)

Comment: USDt and USDC are standards and will be on most chains. EURt sadly is lagging behind and is only on the mainstream ones.

Comment: I think there's a massive potential in enabling people to pay in the Eurozone to use layer 2 solutions with stablecoins, ie EURt. I would love to see it on arbitrum